# how to fetch two different array value in local json file

Tags: json, angular

i want to show `categories` in my `home page` and `menuItems` in the `details page` .
So far i got `categories` shown,in my home.ts, i can only parse categories alone,how to parse both categories and menuitem in my ts,and how to fetch menuItems alone in details page,
i want to match `categories` and `menuItems` by the field `id` .

my data.json

```
{
  “categories”: [
    {
      “id”: “101flashlight”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithmultiplesounds”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/flash.svg”,
      “title”: “FlashLightCrackers”
    },
    {
      “id”: “102zamin”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithsparks”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/zamin.svg”,
      “title”: “ZaminChakkars”
    }
  ],
  “menuItems”: [
    {
      “name”: “1001party”,
      “body”: “infw/detail/confetti/party”,
      “id”: “102zamin”,
      “code”: “”,
      “content”: “2Piecesperbox”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithmultiplesounds”,
      “packing”: “30Boxespercase”,
      “size”: “16x22x8cm”,
      “tags”: “Confetti”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/partycannon.png”,
      “title”: “PartyCannon”,
      “video”: “infw/videos/coming_soon.webm”
    },
    {
      “name”: “1002dollar”,
      “body”: “infw/detail/confetti/dollar”,
      “id”: “102zamin”,
      “code”: “”,
      “content”: “2Piecesperbox”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithmultiplesounds”,
      “packing”: “30Boxespercase”,
      “size”: “52x12x5cm”,
      “tags”: “Confetti”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/dollar.png”,
      “title”: “Dollar”,
      “video”: “infw/videos/coming_soon.webm”
    },
    {
      “name”: “1014elephantspl”,
      “body”: “infw/detail/flash/4splelephant”,
      “id”: “101flashlight”,
      “code”: “”,
      “content”: “5Piecesperpacket”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithmultiplesounds”,
      “packing”: “500Packetspercase”,
      “size”: “16x22x8cm”,
      “tags”: “FlashLightCrackers”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/4splelephant.png”,
      “title”: “4’ElephantSpecialCrackers”,
      “video”: “infw/videos/coming_soon.webm”
    },
    {
      “name”: “1024deluxelak”,
      “body”: “infw/detail/flash/4deluxelak”,
      “id”: “101flashlight”,
      “code”: “”,
      “content”: “5Piecesperpacket”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithmultiplesounds”,
      “packing”: “300Packetspercase”,
      “size”: “16x22x8cm”,
      “tags”: “FlashLightCrackers”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/4deluxelak.png”,
      “title”: “4’DeluxeLakshmiCrackers”,
      “video”: “infw/videos/coming_soon.webm”
    },
    {
      “name”: “1034deluxeele”,
      “body”: “infw/detail/flash/4deluxeele”,
      “id”: “101flashlight”,
      “code”: “”,
      “content”: “5Piecesperpacket”,
      “desc”: “Crackerswithmultiplesounds”,
      “packing”: “300Packetspercase”,
      “size”: “16x22x8cm”,
      “tags”: “FlashLightCrackers”,
      “thumb”: “infw/thumb/4deluxeele.png”,
      “title”: “4’DeluxeElephantCrackers”,
      “video”: “videos/coming_soon.webm”
    }
  ]
}
```

home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  newsData: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private httpProvider:HttpProvider, ) {

this.getdata();
  }
    getdata(){

      this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(
        result => {
          this.newsData=result.categories;

          console.log("Success : "+this.newsData);
        },
        err =>{
          console.error("Error : "+err);
        } ,
        () => {
          console.log('getData completed');
        }
      );
    }
    itemClicked(item) {
      this.navCtrl.push(DetailsBasic, {
        item: item
      });
    }
  }
```

i tried `this.newsData=result.categories.menuItems` ..no luck

I'm sure this is probably a simple question but I am quite new to this and couldn't find how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: To access `menuItems`, use `result.menuItems` and to access 'categories` use `result.categories`.

Comment: using like that results in,it take only one (either Categories or menuItems), as a output and shows that one in all the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your data as such, as you after fetching the data would transform your data as such that the menuitems belonging to each category would be placed under each corresponding category. This solution does not do that, but we filter the menuitems belonging to category chosen. So iterate your categories on your home page, have your existing click event, there we will filter the menu items belonging to that category and pass those menu items to your detail page:

```
itemClicked(item) {
  // filter the menu items based on category
  let menuItems = this.newsData.menuItems.filter(x => x.id === item.id);
  this.navCtrl.push(DetailsBasic, {
    items: menuItems
  });
}
```

Then in your details page capture the array parameter and iterate it your template.

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kxrphz?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.html)

Comment: Great, glad to hear! Have a nice weekend and happy coding! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

menuItems is not a property of categories. try below one.

```
this.newsData=result.menuItems
```

Comment: it will fetch 'menuitems' only,i tried that too, i wanna fetch both categories and menuItems,,and want to show categories in one page,when i click categories i want to show related menuitems  in the other page by matching the record 'id' in both the categories and menuItems